# Запуск нескольких приложений на одном сервере под разными пользователями

Tags: python, nginx, centos7, gunicorn, users

У меня есть два веб-приложения на фласке. Для деплоя я использую связку Nginx + gunicorn. Если запускать из под одним пользователем, то все работает корректно. Я же хочу одно из них апустить под другим пользователем.

Итак, приложение нового пользователя я запускаю так:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Application 2
After=network.target

[Service]
User=app2User
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/app2User/app2
Environment="PATH=/opt/app2venv/bin/"
ExecStart=/opt/app2venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app2.sock -m 007 app:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Первое приложения я запускаю так:

```
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Application 1
After=network.target

[Service]
User=app1User
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/app1User/app1
Environment="PATH=/opt/app1venv/bin/"
ExecStart=/opt/app1venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app1.sock -m 007 app:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Направление на порты в Nginx работает так:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myserver.ru;
        access_log /var/log/app1/access.log;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/app1User/app1/app1.sock;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen          5050;
        server_name     myserver.ru;
        access_log      /var/log/app2/access.log;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/app2User/app2/app2.sock;
        }
    }
```

Итак, после переноса второго приложения и рестарта nginx, первое приложение работает корректно, А второе кидает 502 ошибку. В логе nginx этому соответствует следующая запись:

```
2019/08/02 12:51:55 [crit] 12140#0: *2 connect() to unix:/home/app2User/app2/app2.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.66.6.17, server: myserver.ru, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/app2User/app2/app2.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "myserver.ru:5050", referrer: "http://myserver.ru:5050/"
```

Права на сокет кажатся корректными

```
srwxrwx--- 1 app2User nginx           0 Aug  2 12:38 app2.sock
```

SeLinux отключен.

Думаю, что какая-то проблема с пользователями при запуске nginx, но не могу ее решить.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. 
Надо было добавить пользователя app2User в группу nginx.